# Not automatically lintering with the python interpreter (Python Extension)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently installed VScode on Ubuntu, and now it doesnt automatically linter the code using the python interpreter (as it did on Windows). This is really annoying me because I have to save the file every time I want it to linter.

Any answers are greatly appreciated

*If you need more info, just let me know and I will provide it*

Comment: Hi davfsa you don't seem to have asked a question.  You might want to check out this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting called `Python: Jedi Enabled`[(looks like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWMf8.png). If you switch if off and then restart VSCode, the issue should be fixed

Answer (score 1):

By default, linting for Python is enabled in Visual Studio Code using Pylint, and you can enable other linters of your choice. You can easily enable and disable all linting by using the `Python: Enable Linting` command. Also you can verify your linting settings:

1. Go to `Settings` and check the which linting rules you have enabled :

[image]

2. Go to `Command Palette` and check if the linter is enabled:

[image]

More info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting